# Text input loses focus on change when passed as a cell to Material UI table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the table components of material ui to create a custom table and it works fine for most things but if one of the cells of the table is a text input, it loses focus every time I type a character even though I gave them keys that depend on their props.

There are 3 levels of components before this table is used.

1. `UserDetails` has the user props state and passes it to `UserFiles`.
2. `UserFiles` passes the props to multiple components such as `HealthReport`.
3. `HealthReport` initializes the table's titles and cells such as date pickers and text inputs.

Here's the code for the custom table:

```js
export default function AltTable({ titles, rows }) {
  const RenderRow = ({ row }) => {
    return (
      <TableRow>
        {row.map((cell, index) => (
          <TableCell key={index + (cell && cell?.key)}>
            {cell && cell}
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    );
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {titles.map((data, index) => {
              return <TableCell>{data}</TableCell>;
            })}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, index) => (
            <RenderRow row={row} key={index} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

And here's the shortened code for `HealthReport`. (One thing to note is while `RenderTakenDate` is inside this component, `RenderDescription` is its own file. This is simply because I was trying to see if that would fix it but it did not):

```js
export default function HealthReport({files, setFiles, fileProps, setFileProps, errors, setErrors, setChangeMadeToFiles}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const fileExists = files.healthReport.length > 0;

  const titles = ["Alınan Tarih", "Açıklama", "Doktor Adı", "Dosya"];
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);

  const init = useCallback(async () => {
    let rows = [];
    rows.push([
      <RenderTakenDate 
        key={"empty_hr_taken_date"} 
      />,
      <RenderDescription
        key={"empty_description"}
        fileProps={fileProps}
        setFileProps={setFileProps}
        files={files}
        errors={errors}
        classes={classes}
        setChangeMadeToFiles={setChangeMadeToFiles}
      />
    ]);
    if(fileExists) { 
      for(let i = files.healthReport.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rows.push([
          <RenderTakenDate 
            index={i} 
            key={files.healthReport[i].name + "_hr_taken_date"}
          />,
          <RenderDescription
            index={i}
            key={files.healthReport[i].name + "_description"}
            fileProps={fileProps}
            setFileProps={setFileProps}
            files={files}
            errors={errors}
            classes={classes}
            setChangeMadeToFiles={setChangeMadeToFiles}
          />
        ]);
      }
    }
    await setRows(rows);
  }, [files, fileProps.healthReport, errors]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, [init]);

  const RenderTakenDate = ({index}) => {
    const indexExists = index !== undefined;
    
    const fileExists = indexExists && files.healthReport[index];
    let val = indexExists ? fileProps?.healthReport[index]?.healthReportDateTaken : null;
    
    val === undefined && (val = null);
    
    return(
      <DatePicker
        required
        label={"Date Taken"}
        error={indexExists && errors.healthReportErrors[index] && errors.healthReportErrors[index].healthReportDateTaken}
        value={val}
        disabled={!fileExists}
        shrink={val}
        style={classes.textField}
        onChangeFunc={value => {
          let temp = {...fileProps?.healthReport};
          !temp[index] && (temp[index] = {});
          temp[index].healthReportDateTaken = value;
          
          setFileProps({...fileProps, healthReport: temp});
          setChangeMadeToFiles(true);
        }}
        
      />
    )
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Health Report</h2>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AltTable
          titles={titles}
          rows={rows}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add stackblitz link as it will be better to analyze the issue with the help of actual flow.